# How to remove close button from tabs in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have created some tabs in a `TabPane`. Each time I make a tab it has got a close(x) button on its right side. I don't want the tabs to be removed from the `TtabPane` so I have used:

```
 TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
 Tab tab = new Tab("new tab");
 tab.setContents(new Label("Please help"));
 tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
 tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> e.consume());
```

so that it won't be removed. Is there some way not to display this close button on tab.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can set the `TabClosingPolicy` on a `TabPane`

```
myTabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
```

There are the following possibilities:

- TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS // all tabs can be closed
- TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB // only the selected tab can be closed
- TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE // you cant close

If you are adding classes to `myTabPane.getTabs()` there is also the possibility to set the class to not be closeable (because it needs to extend from `Tab`):

```
setClosable(false);
```

If you define it in the class which extends from `Tab` I guess the policy you set will be useless and is overridden.

Link to the oracle doc:
[JavaFX 8 TabPane.TabClosingPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can also define this using FXML by this code:

```
<TabPane tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
```